# Adjusting the gap between svg icon and text on Material-UI's List component

Tags: material-ui

I've been trying to figure out how to lessen the gap using css with no luck. I created the style object and used leftPosition key but the result was not the one I expected. I was expecting that the text is the only thing that will move. However, if you look at the screenshot specifically the first menu, the icon also moved. What I'd like to achieve is reduce the gap between the svn icon and the text.

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import List from 'material-ui/lib/lists/list';
import ListItem from 'material-ui/lib/lists/list-item';
import ActionGrade from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/action/grade';
import ActionInfo from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/action/info';
import ContentInbox from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/content/inbox';
import ContentDrafts from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/content/drafts';
import ContentSend from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/content/send';
import Divider from 'material-ui/lib/divider';

import Assignment from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/action/assignment';
import Settings from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/action/settings';
import ManageDB from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/content/unarchive';

const style = {
  menu: {
    marginRight: 32,
    marginBottom: 32,
    float: 'left',
    position: 'relative',
    zIndex: 0,
    width: 235,
  },
  rightIcon: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    lineHeight: '24px',
  },
  width: {
    width: 235
  },
  leftPosition: {
    left: 50
  }
};

const LeftNavigation = () => (
  <div>
    <List>
      <ListItem style={style.leftPosition} primaryText="Logs" leftIcon={<Assignment />} />
      <ListItem primaryText="Manage DB" leftIcon={<ManageDB style={style.gap}/>} />
      <ListItem primaryText="Top Issues" leftIcon={<ContentSend style={style.gap}/>} />
      <ListItem primaryText="Settings" leftIcon={<Settings style={style.gap}/>} />
      <ListItem primaryText="Logout" leftIcon={<ContentInbox style={style.gap}/>} />
    </List>
    <Divider />
    <List>
      <ListItem primaryText="All mail" rightIcon={<ActionInfo />} />
      <ListItem primaryText="Trash" rightIcon={<ActionInfo />} />
      <ListItem primaryText="Spam" rightIcon={<ActionInfo />} />
      <ListItem primaryText="Follow up" rightIcon={<ActionInfo />} />
    </List>
  </div>
);

export default LeftNavigation;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is only applicable to Mui 1.x.x. For later versions, please see responses to this answer below.

The ListItem renders a div called innerDiv with 72px left/right padding to render the left/right icon and label with sufficient space. You should try this in the Style -

```
<ListItem innerDivStyle={{paddingLeft: 60}} primaryText="Logs" leftIcon={<Assignment />} />
```

Replace 60 with whatever pleases you.

Comment: is this answer still relevant in material ui 4.0 onwards?

Comment: @MaxCarroll, no, it didn't work with @material-ui/core 4.9.5. I had to use the custom styles overwriting the min-width of the .MuiListItemIcon-root

Comment: you can also override case by case by using the class attribute <ListItemIcon classes={{root: {minWidth: 40}}} /> should also do the job

Answer (score 14):

The accepted solution didn't work for me. Here is what I ended up doing after exploring the DOM. Define the style outside of the component using the makeStyles hook.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    icon: {
        minWidth: '30px',
    }
}));
```

and then apply this class for the ListItemIcon inside of your component definition as:

```
const classes = useStyles();
<ListItemIcon className={classes.icon}> <HelpOutlineIcon/> </ListItemIcon>
```

Hope it helps someone save time.

Comment: This works but why it works? Can you explain why minWidth solves this?

Comment: what is `classes` here?

Comment: updated the answer to include the classes definition @godblessstrawberry

Answer (score 12):

You can add style in ListItemIcon.

```
<ListItemIcon style={{minWidth: '40px'}} >
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me.  I set this in my global css file.

```
.MuiListItemIcon-root {
  min-width: 40px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it globally use overrides in `createMuiTheme`

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiListItemIcon: {
      root: {
        minWidth: 40,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

**Note:**

*If you're using MUI version 5 then locate `createTheme` instead of `createMuiTheme`*

Comment: This answer was more useful to me because it's global. TY

Answer (score 3):

Just information for @Adam Mańkowski 's answer.

In MUI v5.5, you can config your theme like this.

```js
createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiListItemIcon: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          minWidth: 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my 2¢:

```
<ListItemText primary={<div style={{ margin: -25, marginTop: -7, color: 'white', fontSize: 11 }}>Your text here</div>} />
```

Adjusting margin (n.b., it's a negative number) and the top margin you can align the icon (on the left) with your text

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sx` prop instead of `style`, if you want access to the theme object, e.g.:

`<ListItemIcon sx={{minWidth: (theme) => theme.spacing(4)}}>`